# My content is not being created with the features of jquery mobile in a specific part of my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a list dynamically using JQuery.

The problem is: I'm making it in all of my code, but there is only one div that doesn't take the features of JQuery mobile.

```
    db = openDatabase("bdTeste7app", "1.0", "App Docente", 1024);
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM aula WHERE codTurma=' + turmaEscolhida+' group by data', [], function(transaction, results) {
        for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            data[i] = results.rows.item(i).data;
    $('<li data-theme="a"> <a href="#visualizardiario" onclick="getDataSelecionada(\'' + data[i] + '\')" data-transition="slidedown">' + data[i] + '</a></li>').appendTo("#selecionarData").trigger("create");
        }
    });
});
```

That creates the list, but i have no style. In others parts of my code I am doing it well. Thank you.

Comment: Remove `.trigger('create');` after `for` loop add this line: `$('#selecionarData').listview('refresh');`.

Comment: Thank you, Omar. But, could you explain me why it was wrong?

Comment: because enhancement comes after appending all items.